# Convert dataframe with whitespaces to numeric, obstacle - whitespaces (e.g. 3 014.0 i.e. '3\xa0014.0')

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where instead of expected numerical values were stored
data of the type "Object" which looks like 3 014.0 i.e. '3\xa0014.0', instead of 3014.0 - whitespaces (i.e. '\xa0') - create a problem for conversion

**Question:** Is there some way to convert it to numeric ?

**Strange thing:** It appears that I can do conversion of the single element:

```
 float( df.iloc[0,0].replace('\xa0', '') ) # - works
```

but  the same does NOT work for the whole series

```
df['p1'].astype('str').replace('\xa0','') # does nothing
```

--  does nothing

**I tried:**

1. pd.to_numeric - gives: *Unable to parse string*
2. trying to covert to string and then use replace:

df['p1'].astype('str').replace('\xa0','')
*do nothing*

**Data example:**

df.iloc[0:3,0]

```
2017-10-10 11:32:49.895023    3 014.0
2017-10-10 11:33:11.612169    3 013.5
2017-10-10 11:33:22.488124    3 013.0
Name: p1, dtype: object
```

df.iloc[0:3,0]:

```
'3\xa0014.0'
```

Comment: Erm... the character is `"\xa0"`...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, Thank You ! But replace then do nothing

Comment: Are you sure `replace()` should be working in-place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry, should I use inplace somehow ? How ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams float( df.iloc[0,0].replace('\xa0', '') ) - that works   - so single element can be converted, but somehow replace does not work for hole SERIES - how that can be ?

Comment: Use this instead:

`df['p1'] = df['p1'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('\xa0','')))`

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava WOW !!!!!!!! It works !!!!!!!! Thank you very much !!! Please convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it. Can you give a comment please why replace does not work and what is the difference between replace and apply in such situation ? They should do the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead: `df['p1'] = df['p1'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('\xa0','')))`

`df.iloc[0,0]` is a string while `df['p1']` is a pandas series. The `replace` method associated with a string and [with a series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is different. When you call replace on a series, pandas will attempt to replace elements.

For example,

`` df = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'alexander'})`
df['name'].replace('a', 'x') #does nothing`
df['name'].replace('alexander', 'x') #replaces the name alexander with x ``

`df['p1'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('\xa0','')))` applies the replace method to each element (which happens to be a string) in the column p1. You can read more about the method [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Hope this makes things clearer :)